# Why this line isn't going to work on real iOS device?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

In iOS development when using Core Data framework, why this line wont work in real device:

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: 
                  [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] 
                       stringByAppendingPathComponent: @”MyDB.sqlite”]];
```

Doesn't this mean that the DB file is under UUID/Documents directory? or it means it is under UUDI/MyApp.app/Documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`applicationDocumentsDirectory` should be pointing to `GUID/YourApp/Documents`

**This would be a correct usage to get the Documents directory**

```
+(NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

What is the `applicationDocumentsDirectory` code? Assuming you are using it from an example, either from Apple or another reliable source, this should point to your apps Documents folder.

[image]

Comment: @WrightsCS Then the method name is a little bit misleading right? I mean it named applicationDocumentsDirectory.

Comment: Your MyDB.sqlite should be at the root of the Documents directory for your code to work.

Comment: @4bu3li What's misleading about it? No application *ever* has a Documents directory inside the .app bundle. That makes no sense. The method is named such because it returns the Documents directory that's associated with the application, not one that's embedded inside.

Comment: @WrightsCS Actually I was reading a discussion about this in "Head First iPhone Development" book.

Comment: @WrightsCS Upon creating a project based upon a template on Xcode, this method is generated:  - (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}    Will this code runs correctly on a real device?

Comment: How do you know the database is actually created or copied to the Documents directory or even exists? You have to make sure that if you have a skeleton DB, you are copying it over on launch, or making sure it is there on launch.

Comment: Yes, that piece of code will work. But you need to check if the database exists, if not, create / copy it to the Documents directory.